# How do I know how close my enemies are to their deaths?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I am currently in the Olympus Coliseum fighting against Cerberus. It's taking me a few tries, and it feels like the fight is pretty long.

That got me to thinking - most games I play have some sort of HP bar not only for me, the player, but also major bosses.

It doesn't look like KH has something like this, but maybe I am just missing it.

Is there any way to know how close I am to defeating a boss during a fight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike many other games, you actually have to learn an ability in order to see the HP bars of enemies. This ability is called **Scan**, and after you learn it, it will cost 1 AP to use.

Depending on which playstyle you chose, you will be able to learn it at different levels.

- If you chose the **Dream Rod**, you'll learn it at **level 9**
- If you chose the **Dream Shield**, you'll learn it at **level 12**
- If you chose the **Dream Sword**, you'll learn it at **level 15**

Fun fact: This skill is comparable to the Final Fantasy series' skill **Libra** (and is in fact called such in Japanese versions of KH), which serves the same purpose and is also a separate skill/status in many of the games.